# How to get the date that a HERE.COM satellite image is acquired?

Tags: here-api

I am developing an application called Collect Earth which uses a mash-up of freely available Very High Resolution information in order to collect visually interpreted data though Collect Earth ( More info openforis dot org )

I would like to include a geolink to Here Maps as it has such nice satellite imagery available. I have a first draft ( [check here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5lfzgx8bdfzek1/testHereMaps.html?dl=0) ) which already shows the plot layout. I also know how to display a pop-up balloon with the info I want to show ( Satellite Image acquisition date, which is important as we use the tool to report on Land Use and Land Use Change).

What I don't know is **how to get the acquisition date of the Satellite Image shown in Here maps**! I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Any ideas? Is there anything that could be used?

In Bing Maps [I already have a solution](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kttx6zb4ayomi6d/CollectEarthandBingMaps.jpg?dl=0), so I am looking at replicating something like this in Here Maps.

Comment: Hi, I also need to access the acquisition dates of the satellite images shown in BingMaps. You mentioned you have a solution for  Bing Maps, but your link doesn't work anymore. Would you mind to share it with us, again?

Comment: Hi, a bit late but...you can look at the code to get the dates of the Bing Maps mosaic here : https://github.com/openforis/collect-earth/blob/master/collect-earth/collect-earth-app/resources/collectBing.fmt

Comment: I wrote a small blogpost on "How accurate are the recording dates for images in Microsoft Bing Maps?" https://philippgaertner.github.io/2018/11/microsoft-bing-maps/

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately We don't provide the acquisition date of the satellite imagery.